# Is [2-party d3-rolling with maximum probability 1/2] known to imply one-way functions?

Tags: cr.crypto-security, relativization

Most things in complexity-based cryptography (for examples, see [page 4](http://slideplayer.com/slide/8511059)) are known to imply

the existence of one-way functions, especially after [this paper](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~iftachh/papers/TightCF/TightCoingFlipping_CR.pdf) proved that implication for weak coin-flipping with any constant bias. ​ However, [this paper](http://www2.seas.gwu.edu/~hoeteck/pubs/pessiland-tcc06.pdf) shows a relativized world with non-trivial 2-round argument systems but no one-way functions, which makes we wonder about the

possibility of complexity-based cryptography, beyond ideal [SNARKs](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=succinct+non-interactive+argument+of+knowledge), without one-way functions.

With that in mind, I initially thought about multi-party versions of honest-majority coin-flipping

with negligible bias, but discovered that there were too many possible specifications

for me to decide which of them to ask about. ​ (For example, are there secret channels,

is broadcast available, [what are the requirements in case of abort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault_tolerance)?)

Accordingly, I'm instead asking about 2 parties choosing an element from {0,1,2}.

> Consider the 2-party functionality:
>   
>   If the parties are both corrupt or both honest then choose y uniformly from {0,1,2}.
>   
>   Otherwise, receive an element x of ​ {0,1,2} ​ from the
>   
>   adversary and choose y uniformly from ​ {0,1,2} [-](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html) {x} .
>   
>   In either case, output y to both parties.
>   
>   Is it known that if there is a secure 2-party implementation
>   
>   of that functionality then one-way functions exist?

(Obviously, one doesn't need to care about what happens when both parties are corrupt.

Slightly less obviously, when both parties are honest, it suffices to make sure they get the *same* value, since the protocol could be modified to start with one party choosing an element of {0,1,2} uniformly at random and then at the end, adding that to the inner protocol's output mod 3.)